Switching supervisors after a first semester in Master's due to lacking supervisor expertise?
I am currently in the exact same situation as another user, but after wrapping up my first semester in a Master's degree. I initially accepted the offer because the proposed topic genuinely seemed interesting and because I didn't really have any other option. I also thought that at least one of the supervisors would have some fundamental knowledge of the proposed topic, since that one had allegedly been working on it for some time. But after a couple of meetings, two of the three openly admitted to not having any idea of what's going on (their combined expertise is useful for one small aspect of the project, or roughly 5%), while the third doesn't seem to understand that he doesn't understand the topic. In short, I feel like I'm going to have to spend two years teaching division to people who don't know what numbers are.
Now, the professor in one of my classes offered me to join his lab, thinking I am an undergraduate. With all due respect to my current supervisors, I feel like he would be an all-around upgrade due to his very solid background.
My gut tells me to switch, but I don't know how it is for other people and worry that I'm overthinking it, overdramatizing it or just being entitled. There are some other things that seem like red flags to me, but I won't divulge them out of privacy concerns.
The reason why this is not a duplicate of the post I linked (and others) is because of the different sunk cost and the different scope of the PhD/MSc programs. I don't think it would be that big of an issue if I had four years to spare, but I don't see this project bearing fruit in two years without it falling into redundancy. Especially with my supervisors being unable to clearly communicate what they're even looking for (when it turned out their proposal was way too far-fetched, I was told to redefine it myself despite, you know, not having much knowledge about the topic myself).

Actually, a closer match to your situation might be this one: Is it too early to switch advisors if I just finished my first semester as a master's student?. And the answer there, while concise, is dead on.

What domain are you in? You mention joining a lab but you make no specific mention of the sunk cost. Is this something with actual experimentation or engineering that you would have to start from scratch, or "just" theory work?

This question is similar to: Is it too early to switch advisors if I just finished my first semester as a master's student?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MisterMiyagi By sunk cost I was referring to time. But yeah this is in engineering.
